# AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() not found in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using External Login providers in my mvc5 application.In my controller I can use below to check if there is any external login info

```
await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

How can I use this in my razor view to check if external login info exists or not. 
I used below

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()==null)
    {
     ...............
    }
```

Which seems to work but

> HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()

still not null even after logout
I need to show/hide some information depending on it in the ExternalLogInConfirmation Page

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension method for this

```
namespace MyApp.ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class Extentions
        {
        public static bool IsExternalLogInfoExists(this IPrincipal principal)
        {

           return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().
                  Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo()==null?false:true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my view

```
if (!User.IsExternalLogInfoExists())
    {
     //show/hide any thing
    }
```

Of course on top you need add namespace. On my case

```
@using MyApp.ExtensionMethods;
```