# MVC Razor view to detect if authenticated user has social login provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

Is there any way in an MVC Razor view to do something like:

```
if (user has associated/logged in with a Facebook account)
```

I think in code behind I can retrieve it like so:

```
var logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(loggedInUserId);
string loginProvider = "Facebook"
string providerKey = logins.Where(c => c.LoginProvider == loginProvider)
                     .Select(c => c.ProviderKey)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

However a helper class doesn't have the context to get 'UserManager' (I don't think).  I'm not sure if I'm reinventing the wheel here or if there's a simple way to do this....

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Sorry....I probably should have mentioned I want to add this logic to a shared partial view (my main menu) that I want to use across all pages.  Hence i think a ViewModel is probably out?

Comment: You could make a viewModel with the property `public bool IsFacebookUser {get; set;}` and send that model to the view instead of whatever model you were using.

Comment: Sorry....I probably should have mentioned I want to add this logic to a shared partial view (my main menu) that I want to use across all pages.  Hence i think a ViewModel is probably out?

Comment: What version of .net are you on?  Sounds like a good use for a viewComponent if that is available.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components

Comment: .Net 4.6.2.....I'll have a look at View Components.....thanks.

Comment: Another option would be to add a custom claim to the principal then use a claims extension to access it.  It takes a bit of setup but once it is done accessing the value is as simple as `User.IsFaceBookUser()` and is available in the view as long as you add the extension namespace.  This is a _super_ handy way of adding values to the principal which get used over and over in different views.

Comment: NurdyGuy, that sounds like exactly what I wanted but I might well be out of my depth.  I was hoping for a built in method like just that...similar to how I can say 'Request.IsAuthenticated' or 'Roles.IsUserInRole' etc....  I'll have a fish around the web.

Comment: It isn't that hard but you do have to change things in a couple of places.  this is the basic class you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.principalextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.0  I'll try to find other helpful links for you.

Comment: I might have a play with this later too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557936/authenticationmanager-getexternallogininfoasync-not-found-in-razor-view

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a working solution.  In a helper class I've created:

```
    public static string GetLoginType(this IPrincipal user)
    {

        if (!(user.Identity is ClaimsIdentity)) return "";

        string loginProvider = ((ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity).Claims
                                               .Where(c => c.Type.Equals("ExternalLoginProvider"))
                                               .Select(c => c.Value)
                                               .FirstOrDefault();

        return loginProvider;

    }
```

and in my razor view I have:

```
@using Namespace.Helpers

if (User.GetLoginType() == "Facebook")
{
    //do something
}
```

and in my external login sign-in method i currently have:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent, string loginProvider)
    {


AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        //create new claim called ExternalLoginProvider with a value of for example, "Facebook"
        Claim clm = new Claim("ExternalLoginProvider", loginProvider);
        identity.AddClaim(clm);


        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```